# How to start a Blazor Webassembly project in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, blazor, webassembly

I can't start a Blazor project in Visual Studio.

Visual Studio version: Community 2019 (16.6.4)

I have tried:

- Find out if Blazor templates are limited to Professional or Enterprise VS installations.
- Repairing using the installer
- Running the following command as recommended by other solutions: `dotnet new --install Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates::3.2.0-preview1.20073.1` in both the NuGet CLI and CMD.

No matter what I do, I don't see anything related to Blazor when I click "Create a new project" in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

To start a Blazor Webassembly project in Visual Studio 2019 you will need to install the WebAssembly template from the command line, to install the latest preview execute the following command via the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio.

dotnet new --install Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates::3.1.0-preview3.19555.2

With the WebAssembly template installed, you can now create a client-side Blazor project. Start by creating a new Blazor App project.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not getting anything Blazor as an option when creating a new project.

Comment: You should have .NET CORE 3.1 or higher version of SDK installed. You can check the installed version using dotnet --version command in cmd.
If you dont have it here is the link:
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1

Comment: I have 3.1.302 installed.